# Don't see all points in Grafana on lower scales

Tags: grafana, outliers, graphite

On lower scale I am obviously seeing several outliers, maximal of which is 18211

[image]

if I zoom in then I am starting to see additional outliers

[image]

Is it possible to configure Grafana to show all points all the time or aggregate them differently?

Backend is Graphite.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible due to space limitations

For example:

Suppose you have 60 places and you want to fill them with numbers
If the time period is one hour, then in each of these places it will display the metrics stored of every minute
But if you make this interval smaller and convert it to a minute, each of these places will display the metrics stored of every second.

Comment: I would say the underlying technology should allow controlled aggregation rather than just dropping some random data

Comment: It's not random data. It's a metric that stored at that time. For example grafana shows you  number that stored at 15:33

Comment: note, that timestamps are different